# Login from Sample with SOAP

Tags: c#, exception, soap, webserver, yodlee

I'm trying to connect to the server, but as a function of **cobrandLoginService.loginSobrand** example for C# there is an exception: 
**java.lang.NillPointerEsseption**

In the settings are correct сobrand login and password, to TestDrive authentication passes.

Web address may be incorrect server? Set this in my profile.

What could be the problem and what information is needed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SOAP or REST sample?

If SOAP -  then make sure that you have all the parameters filled correctly in the APP.config file of the sample provided by Yodlee.

If REST -  Then you can call do the cobrand login by make the REST call based on this [article](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/coblogin)

Comment: I use SOAP 
all options, as far as I can tell are true. 
Why at the Web server error occurs? 

https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services 
The service cannot be found for the endpoint reference (EPR)

Comment: My question is exactly if the parameters are correct? http://rixtrema.com/App.config

Comment: You can check for the SOAP service by opening https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/listServices and verify if the service name you are trying to call is correct or not.

Comment: Oh, you want to use different servers for different functions, I have everything worked out, thanks a lot! 
And sorry for my English :)

Comment: Glad to hear that you have everything working now. Just an advice , please use the version 2013Q3 (ex - https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/services/CobrandLoginService_2013Q3) and the corresponding WSDL (download link - https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Sample_Apps/Wsdls)